# How do I reload files in PHP while the program is still running?

Tags: php, bots, irc

I'm helping develop a PHP IRC robot and I'd like to know how I could reload the bot's config via an IRC command. Could someone give a sort of basic idea of how to do this task? I was thinking maybe the bot could re-require_once the config file and then restart, but I don't know how to do that (When It runs die(), it stops the entire program so it can't revive itself.)

Comment: Is this some sort of spam bot?

Comment: Err, no it isn't. It's an IRC bot...

Comment: I apologize, I asked out of ignorance, then I asked a [question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/158947) on the SE programmers site because I was not familiar with benevolent uses of IRC bots. I see now they are used basically as channel admin tools. (as well as spamming and other malicious activities)

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP program will likely be event-based. You'll be listening on a port. You'll have a point in your code that will be called whenever someone writes something in the channel.

At this exact point, you can inject the logic that loads the configuration from disk.

You can also have a wrapper around this logic that serves as a time-based cache: it doesn't reload the config every time a post is made - and instead looks it up in memory.